# How to add number of input fields on change another input field value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 rows and 3 columns in the table. Quantity field is input field.

I want to add new input fields in another column when anyone changes input field value.

Now, I am using below code:

```
<td class="a-right">
        <span class="nobr">
                    <div class="newFields"></div>              
        </span>
    </td>

<script>
jQuery(function() {

    var input = jQuery('<input type="text" />');
    var newFields = jQuery('');
   jQuery('.awrma-items-count').on('change', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
                var n = this.value || 0;
                        for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
                            var newInput = input.clone();
                            newFields = newFields.add(newInput);

                            newInput.appendTo('.newFields');
                        }
            });

    function removeFields(n) {
        var removeField = newFields.slice(n).remove();
        newFields = newFields.not(removeField);
    }
});
</script>
```

When I use above code, It is adding the number of fields multiply with the number of rows(2*3=6 fields) in each row. But I want to add the input fields only in the same row.

for example: If I add quantity 2, then 2*3=6 input fields add all 3 rows. But I want to add these 2 input fields only that row.
see screenshot: http://nimb.ws/RmKGg2

How can I achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified above code. Please check below updated code and I hope this will be useful to you.

```
<table id="shopping-cart-table" class="cart-table data-table" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Serial #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>First Product</td>
            <td>TEST001</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="awrma-items-count" /></td>
            <td class="a-right">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Second Product</td>
            <td>TEST002</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="awrma-items-count" /></td>
            <td class="a-right">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Third Product</td>
            <td>TEST003</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty" class="awrma-items-count" /></td>
            <td class="a-right">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        var input = jQuery('<input type="text" />');
        var newFields = jQuery('');
        jQuery('.awrma-items-count').on('change', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var n = this.value || 0;
            var serialNumber = jQuery(this).parent('td').next('td');
            serialNumber.empty();

            for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
                var newInput = input.clone();
                newFields = newFields.add(newInput);
                newInput.appendTo(serialNumber);
            }
        });

        function removeFields(n) {
            var removeField = newFields.slice(n).remove();
            newFields = newFields.not(removeField);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code-

```
<script>

    var input = jQuery('<input type="text" name="qtyinput[]" />');
    var newFields = jQuery('');

       function generate_input(n, item)
       {
                var n = jQuery("."+n).val() || 0;
                console.log(n);
                jQuery('.newFields-'+item).html('');

                for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
                    var newInput = input.clone();
                    newFields = newFields.add(newInput);
                    newInput.appendTo('.newFields-'+item);
                }
        }

    function removeFields(n) {
        var removeField = newFields.slice(n).remove();
        newFields = newFields.not(removeField);
    }

</script>
```

call function `generate_input(n, item)` onkeyup in your input tag